# Phonegap android and iPhone - google map api v3 with navigation voice api

Tags: cordova, google-maps-api-3, navigation, voice

How do i implement google map api v3 with navigation voice api in phonegap android and iPhone. i have implemented direction service using google api with phonegap geolocation, but not able to implement voice api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps API v3 does not provide the voice feature at all.
And Google Maps API v3 and Google Maps applications are completely different ones.
So if you want to implement the voice navigation, you need to prepare it.

Fortunately, org.apache.cordova.plugin.tts plugin provides that function for Android.
https://github.com/domaemon/org.apache.cordova.plugin.tts

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
  tts.speak("Hello");
});
```